# Laravel 10 - polymorphic set type field value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a class which is expending parent model class:

```
class SoulForm extends Soul implements AdminFormInterface
{ .... }
```

Parent class:

```
class Soul extends Model
{
   public function sheet(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Sheet::class, 'sheetable');
    }
}
```

This is controller where the save method is located:

```
class AdminSoulController extends Controller
{
    use FormRedirect;
    use AdminForm;

    public static string $formRoute = 'admin.soul.form';
    public static string $tableRoute = 'admin.soul.index';

    public static string $model = SoulForm::class;

    public function save(SoulRequest $request, ?SoulForm $soul)
    {
        $data = collect($request->validated());

        if ($request->file('icon'))
        {
            $this->iconUpload($request);
        }

        $soul->fill($data->only(['name', 'order', 'description'])->all());
        $soul->save();

        $sheet = new Sheet();
        $sheet->fill($data->except(['name', 'order', 'description'])->all());

        $soul->sheet()->save($sheet);

        return $this->redirectAction($request->get('action'), $soul->fresh());
    }
    
}
```

Is there a way to save **sheetable_type** as **Modules\Soul\Entities\Soul** and not sa**Modules\Soul\Entities\SoulForm**

Comment: That is model path I don't know if you can change the model and still search on the correct  model. You can change the name of type if you want by [Custom Polymorphic Types](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types)